# HTML5 Mutliple <address> tags in the same page

Tags: html

Is it bad practice to include two address tags in the same document inside the same article?
The subtext is a press kit rundown of a company, including some facts about it.

eg.

```
<address>
   company email: some@email.address
</address>

<p>
   founded at: 1970, 1st of January. 
</p>

<address>
   address:<br>
   some place<br>
   earth<br>
   milky way
</address>
```

Are there any significant outcomes for doing this?
With what machines/browsers/websites are the address tags significant?
How does this affect search engines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use address tags twice in your document for example, You have two `article` tags in your `document` and those have different information like `email address`,`Phone number`etc. Then what is the solution? Obviously you cannot use single `address` tag for this.

```
<article>
    article one 
    <address>
    written by: John,
    Email: email@email.com 
    </address>
</article>

**<!-- Article Two -->**

<article>
    article two 
    <address>
    written by: Doe,
    Email: email@email.com 
    </address>
</article>
```

In this situation you need to address tags. I don't think there is any browser which does not support it. Because this tag is around since HTML3. Go through these links to clear your confusions. [Address element by Jack Osborne](http://html5doctor.com/the-address-element/),
[w3c Specs](http://w3c.github.io/html/sections.html#the-address-element)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The context is that there are several facts about a company inside a press kit page. While some facts could be contained inside regular <div> tags, others could be used with the <address> tag. I'll update the post to add more subtext. Thank you as well for the articles, I'll read through them.